# encryption/decryption not working in laravel 4

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-5

On registration, password is getting saved as intended encrypted but while login, it is throwing a message that password is not matching, because encrypted password is not decrypting while login. Can any one help me out with this ? I want to login successfully with encrypted password.

Here is my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use Session;
use Redirect;
use App\User;
use App\Http\Requests\UserRequest as UserRequest;
// use App\Http\Requests\CreateArticleRequest as CreateArticleRequest;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\View\Middleware\ErrorBinder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Hash;
use Crypt;
use Bcrypt;


class ctrl extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
public function registration_function(Request $request)
  {
      $nam_value = $request->nam;
      $email_value = $request->r_email;
      $password_value = $request->r_password;
      $city_value = $request->city;
      $login_email = $request->l_email;
      $login_password = $request->l_password;
      $bcrypt = new Bcrypt(15);
      $password_value = $bcrypt->hash($password_value);
      $login_password = $bcrypt->verify($password_value, $login_password);

      // $password_value = Crypt::encrypt($password_value);
      // $login_password = Crypt::encrypt($password_value);
      if($email_value)
      {
      $valid_user = DB::table('registered')
                        ->where('email',$email_value)
                        ->get();
      if($valid_user)
      {
        return redirect('makelogin_page')->with('status_validate','You are already registered with us, Plaese login, Did you forgot your password ?');
      }
      else
      {
        $reg=DB::table('registered')->insert(['name' => $nam_value, 'email' => $email_value, 'password'=>$password_value,'city'=>$city_value]);
        return redirect('makelogin_page')->with('status','Registered Successfully');
      }
    }
    else
    {
      $log_display = DB::table('registered')
                        ->where('email',$login_email)
                        ->where('password',$login_password)
                        ->get();
      if($log_display)
      {
        return redirect('dodofront');
      }
      else
      {
        return redirect('makelogin_page')->with('status','Please enter the valid credentials, Did you forgot your password ?');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my blade.php page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Dashboard | Design Dodo</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="bootstrap/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
<body>
  <br/>
  <div class="container">
    <h3>New user ?</h3>
    <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#registration">Register</button>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="registration" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Registration</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Please Register Yourself Here</p>
            <form role="form" action="registration_page" method="get">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nam" placeholder="Your Name Please" style="width:265px;" required/>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="r_email" placeholder="Your Email Please" style="width:265px;" required/>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="r_password" placeholder="Please enter a password" style="width:265px;" required/>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city" placeholder="Please enter your city" style="width:265px;" required/>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Register">
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <h3>Existing user ?</h3>
    <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login">Login</button>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="login" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Login</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Please Login Here</p>
            <form role="form" action="login_page" method="get">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="l_email" placeholder="Your Email Please" style="width:265px;" required/>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="l_password" placeholder="Please enter a password" style="width:265px;" required/>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="login">
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

And here is route

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::auth();

Route::get('/registration_page','ctrl@registration_function');

Route::get('/login_page','ctrl@registration_function');
```

THis code is throwing an error which is

```
FatalErrorException in ctrl.php line 40:
Class 'Bcrypt' not found
```

Please help me to solve this issue

Comment: use bcrypt function instead of a object Bcrypt

Comment: could you explain it with an example ?